# What does if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; mean in .ksh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

I have a following piece of code that says if everything is executed mail a person if it fails mail the person with a error message.

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  mailx -s" could not PreProcess files" xyz@abcd.com
else            
  mailx -s" PreProcessed files" xyz@abcd.com
fi
done
```

I am new to linux coding I want to understand what `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];` means

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Breaking it down, simple terms:

```
[[ and ]]
```

... signifies a test is being made for truthiness.

```
$?
```

... is a variable holding the exit code of the last run command.

```
-ne 0
```

... checks that the thing on the left (`$?`) is "not equal" to "zero".  In UNIX, a command that exits with zero succeeded, while an exit with any other value (1, 2, 3... up to 255) is a failure.

Answer (score 7):

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];
```

Is checking return code of immediately previous this if condition.

- `$?` means return code
- `$? -ne 0` means previous command returned an error since 0 is considered success

Comment: So in simple term it means, if the previous code has not done its job mail with error and if the code has done its job just mail, right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely @Rahulsawant

Comment: I would add that -ne stands for "not equal"

Answer (score 2):

If the previous command returned an error return code.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, the snippet is part of code that looks something like:

```
 for var in list of words; do
   cmd $var
   if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      mailx -s" could not PreProcess files" xyz@abcd.com
    else            
      mailx -s" PreProcessed files" xyz@abcd.com
   fi
 done
```

Which could (and should) be re-written more simply as:

```
for var in list of words; do
  if ! cmd $var; then
    message="could not PreProcess files"
  else
    message="PreProcessed files
  fi
  mailx -s" $message" xyz@abcd.com
done
```

The `[[ $? -ne 0 ]]` clause is a hackish way to check the return value of `cmd`, but it is almost always unnecessary to check `$?` explicitly.  Code is nearly always cleaner if you let the shell do the check by invoking the command in the if clause.

Comment: Actually in many cases it's not even necessary to have an `if` clause, just do `cmd || only_executed_when_return_code_from_cmd_is_not_equal_to_success`